# How to sort range using Apps script based on a column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this demo sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pGkTrudeDfv7Xkm7ZGM0fmQzSCqU05hFVhuczJ4cWCQ/edit?usp=sharing

I'm using this code to sort my data,

```
function SortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Ventas");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A4:S");
  var SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 19, ascending: false},  
{column: 18, ascending: false},
{column: 13, ascending: false},
{column: 7 , ascending: false},
{column: 2 , ascending: true},
{column: 1 , ascending: true},
{column: 3 , ascending: true}
]
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
}
```

which works ok

What I need is:
if Column M contains 'Entregado' to sort in this way,
if contains 'Cobrar' sort in different order,
if contains 'Apartado' sort in different order,
if contains 'Preventa' sort in different order,
and if contains any other value to sort them in a different way

is this possible?

thanks!

---

Edit: I'm trying this code, but its not working as expected

```
function ColumnContainString(column,string) {
  var column=column || 13;//used for initial testing
  var string=string || 'test';//used for initial testing
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName("Ventas");
  var cA=sheet.getRange(4,column,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<cA.length;i++) {
    if(cA[i][0].toString().indexOf(string)>-1) {//you may wish to change this line to some regular expression to find only words
      Logger.log(i+1);
      return(i+1);
    }
  }
  Logger.log('-1');
  return -1;
}

function SortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Ventas");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A4:S");
 
 if(ColumnContainString(13,'Entregado')==-1) {
    var SORT_ORDER = [
    {column: 19, ascending: false},  // M
    {column: 18, ascending: true},   // H
    {column: 1 , ascending: true},   // Fecha
    {column: 2 , ascending: true},   // Cliente
    {column: 3 , ascending: true}    // Sabor
    ]   
      range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  }
  
  if(ColumnContainString(13,'Cobrar')==-1) {
    var SORT_ORDER = [
    {column: 18, ascending: true},   // H
    {column: 13, ascending: true},   // Estatus
    {column: 7 , ascending: false},  // Vendio
    {column: 2 , ascending: true},   // Cliente
    {column: 3 , ascending: true},   // Sabor
    {column: 1 , ascending: true}    // Fecha
    ]  
      range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  }
  
  if(ColumnContainString(13,'Pendiente')==-1) {
    var SORT_ORDER = [
    {column: 18, ascending: true},   // H
    {column: 13, ascending: true},   // Estatus
    {column: 7 , ascending: false},  // Vendio
    {column: 2 , ascending: true},   // Cliente
    {column: 3 , ascending: true},   // Sabor
    {column: 1 , ascending: true}    // Fecha
    ]  
      range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  }
  
  if(ColumnContainString(13,'Preventa')==-1) {
    var SORT_ORDER = [
    {column: 18, ascending: true},   // H
    {column: 13, ascending: true},   // Estatus
    {column: 7 , ascending: false},  // Vendio
    {column: 2 , ascending: true},   // Cliente
    {column: 3 , ascending: true},   // Sabor
    {column: 1 , ascending: true}    // Fecha
    ]  
      range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  }
  
  if(ColumnContainString(13,'Apartado')==-1) {
    var SORT_ORDER = [
    {column: 18, ascending: true},   // H
    {column: 13, ascending: true},   // Estatus
    {column: 2 , ascending: true},   // Cliente
    {column: 3 , ascending: true},   // Sabor
    {column: 1 , ascending: true}    // Fecha
    ]  
      range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  }
}
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand about ``What I need is``, can I ask you about your question? If your shared Spreadsheet is the situation before the script, which you want, is run, can you provide the result after the script was run?

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
function ColumnContainString(column,string) {
  var column=column || 13;//used for initial testing
  var string=string || 'test';//used for initial testing
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName("Ventas");
  var cA=sheet.getRange(4,column,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<cA.length;i++) {
    if(cA[i][0].toString().indexOf(string)>-1) {//you may wish to change this line to some regular expression to find only words
      Logger.log(i+1);
      return(i+1);
    }
  }
  Logger.log('-1');
  return -1;
}
```

The main function will have expressions like this:

```
if(ColumnContainString(13,'Entregado')==-1) {
//Then put your sort functions in here
}
```

So you might rewrite you current function in this way:

```
function SortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Ventas");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A4:S");
  if(ColumnContainString(13,'Entregado')==-1) {
    var SORT_ORDER = [
      {column: 19, ascending: false},  
      {column: 18, ascending: false},
      {column: 13, ascending: false},
      {column: 7 , ascending: false},
      {column: 2 , ascending: true},
      {column: 1 , ascending: true},
      {column: 3 , ascending: true}];
      range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  }
  if(ColumnContainString(13,'Apartado')==-1) {
    var SORT_ORDER = [
      {column: 19, ascending: false},  
      {column: 18, ascending: false},
      {column: 13, ascending: false},
      {column: 7 , ascending: false},
      {column: 2 , ascending: true},
      {column: 1 , ascending: true},
      {column: 3 , ascending: true}];//change sort order
      range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand where I have to put the main function inside your function

Comment: The main function or whatever you want to call it will use ColumnContainString() function to test if a column contains a string.  Please note that I changed the answer just a bit.

Comment: im trying the code I paste on the question, but is not working if you can see the shared spreadsheet, I don't know what im doing wrong